# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget for CarouselSlider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have used CarouselSlider for my other projects but the first time I could not find the reason why it gives that warning. Here is a simplified code part. I did not use any flexible or expanded widget in Stack or its parent. Mostly answers about that but there has to be a point that I am missing. Here is the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) of dependency. Do you have any suggestions?

```
return Scaffold(
 body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                      70.h -
                      MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top) *
                  0.35,
              child: slider()),
            ])
         
);

Stack slider() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
              autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              autoPlay: true,
              // aspectRatio: 2.3,
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                      70.h -
                      MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top) *
                  0.35,
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.scale,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                });
              }),
          items: images
              .map(
                (item) => Center(child: item),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                          70.h -
                          MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top) *
                      0.3),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: images.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 8.w,
                    height: 8.h,
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.w, horizontal: 4.h),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: ColorSelect.color
                            .withOpacity(_current == entry.key ? 1 : 0.4)),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you please share the error message...

Comment: Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. This the only error message that I see. Every time that slider works and image is changing. This message shows up